# How can we display specific row data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a bootstrap card with Read More Option in my CodeIgniter view. On clicking the button, url is displaying the selected card ID, but only the first row from the data base is fetching. Not sure, where I am doing it wrong.

Code for Controller starts here

```
public function getDetails()
{
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT swo_brief_intro, swo_image_heading FROM services_offered");

        $row = $query->row();

        if (isset($row))
        {
                echo $row->swo_image_heading;
                echo $row->swo_brief_intro;
        }

        
}
```

Code for View starts here

```
<div class="row clearfix">

<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM services_offered LIMIT 15");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-4 bottommargin-sm'>";
        echo "<div class='feature-box media-box fbox-bg'>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-media'>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='$row->swo_images' alt='Featured Box Image' style='height:250px; width:450px;'></a></div>";
        echo "<div class='fbox-content fbox-content-lg'>";
        $string = $row->swo_brief_intro;
        $string = word_limiter($string, 15);
        echo "<h3 class='nott ls0 font-weight-semibold'>$row->swo_image_heading<span class='subtitle font-secondary font-weight-light ls0'>$string</span></h3>";
        echo "<a href='Fetch/getDetails/{$row->id}' class='button-link border-0 color btn-edit'>Read More</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";


    }
?>
```

Please assist. Thanks

Comment: use `active record` and use `where` condition instead of simple query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You forgot to add Id parameter in your function.

b) As well as forgot to change query based on that.

```
public function getDetails($id)
{

    $row = $this 
            -> db
            -> select('swo_brief_intro, swo_image_heading')
            -> where('<put here id column name>', $id)
            -> limit(1)
            -> get('services_offered')
            -> row();
    
    if (isset($row))
    {
        echo $row->swo_image_heading;
        echo $row->swo_brief_intro;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: after implementing the above code, I am not able to display the data in the bootstrap modal. The controller should display the contents inside a model. How to display data into the modal.

Comment: @VIVEKROBINKUJUR  for that you have to ask new question.